Trouble opening images from dataset in Python Keras model
Firstly, I'm new to Keras and Tensorflow, so please be nice :)
Environment:

Python 3.12.3 on MacOS Sonoma 14.5
VSCode (Latest Version)
Tensorflow 2.16.1
Matplotlib 3.9.0
Keras 3.3.3

I've been following this guide from Keras' official site to create a handwritten text recognition model (HTR) in Python https://keras.io/examples/vision/handwriting_recognition/ but have run into some issues opening & reading the dataset from this GitHub download link (https://github.com/sayakpaul/Handwriting-Recognizer-in-Keras/releases/download/v1.0.0/IAM_Words.zip).
I've updated the code in a few places if and when I spot problems, but it's failing when the model training starts:
2024-06-02 19:26:11.552695: W tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:404] Local rendezvous is aborting with status: OUT_OF_RANGE: End of sequence
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Ugreen SSD/Py/keras-HTR-ENG/model.py", line 355, in <module>
    prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/Ugreen SSD/Py/keras-HTR-ENG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/models/model.py", line 143, in __new__
    return functional.Functional(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/Ugreen SSD/Py/keras-HTR-ENG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/utils/tracking.py", line 26, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/Ugreen SSD/Py/keras-HTR-ENG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 162, in __init__
    Function.__init__(self, inputs, outputs, name=name, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/Ugreen SSD/Py/keras-HTR-ENG/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/ops/function.py", line 62, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: `inputs` argument cannot be empty. Received:
inputs=[]
outputs=<KerasTensor shape=(None, 32, 79), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_20>

This is the problematic code:
class EditDistanceCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, pred_model):
        super().__init__()
        self.prediction_model = pred_model

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        edit_distances = []

        for i in range(len(validation_images)):
            labels = validation_labels[i]
            predictions = self.prediction_model.predict(validation_images[i])
            edit_distances.append(calculate_edit_distance(labels, predictions).numpy())

        print(
            f"Mean edit distance for epoch {epoch + 1}: {np.mean(edit_distances):.4f}"
        )
epochs = 10  # To get good results this should be at least 50.

model = build_model()
prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
    model.get_layer(name="image").input, model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
)
edit_distance_callback = EditDistanceCallback(prediction_model)

# Train the model.
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=validation_ds,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[edit_distance_callback],
)

I could be wrong, but it seems to me that it's passing empty values to keras.models.Model. I know that it's discovering the images correctly, as it's reporting the correct number of images:
Total params: 423,823 (1.62 MB)
 Trainable params: 423,823 (1.62 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)

All of the pictures are .png and haven't been edited from the original dataset. I've also downloaded the dataset from a few different places just to test if they've become corrupted.
There's probably important info that I've missed, but I've added all I can think to at the moment. Thank you for all the help.
Edit: Heres the code for building the model.
def build_model():
    # Inputs to the model
    input_img = keras.Input(shape=(image_width, image_height, 1), name="image")
    labels = keras.layers.Input(name="label", shape=(None,))

    # First conv block.
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(
        32,
        (3, 3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv1",
    )(input_img)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool1")(x)

    # Second conv block.
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(
        64,
        (3, 3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv2",
    )(x)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool2")(x)

    # We have used two max pool with pool size and strides 2.
    # Hence, downsampled feature maps are 4x smaller. The number of
    # filters in the last layer is 64. Reshape accordingly before
    # passing the output to the RNN part of the model.
    new_shape = ((image_width // 4), (image_height // 4) * 64)
    x = keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=new_shape, name="reshape")(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense1")(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

    # RNNs.
    x = keras.layers.Bidirectional(
        keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25)
    )(x)
    x = keras.layers.Bidirectional(
        keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25)
    )(x)

    # +2 is to account for the two special tokens introduced by the CTC loss.
    # The recommendation comes here: https://git.io/J0eXP.
    x = keras.layers.Dense(
        len(char_to_num.get_vocabulary()) + 2, activation="softmax", name="dense2"
    )(x)

    # Add CTC layer for calculating CTC loss at each step.
    output = CTCLayer(name="ctc_loss")(labels, x)

    # Define the model.
    model = keras.models.Model(
        inputs=[input_img, labels], outputs=output, name="handwriting_recognizer"
    )
    # Optimizer.
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    # Compile the model and return.
    model.compile(optimizer=opt)
    return model


# Get the model.
model = build_model()
model.summary()


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

maybe you have to use Model( input=..., output=... ) to assign values to correct variables.

I think you have to check what you have in model.get_layer(name="image").input. If it empty then you have to check code which creates this element. You didn't show this part so we can't help more at this moment.

It turns out that there are a few missing pieces needed to make this work. Unfortunately, it hasn't been included in the official Keras documentation. Nevertheless, I've asked the Keras team for help over on Github and received this response:

There needs to be change at few line in handwritten recognition code.
predictions_decoded = keras.ops.nn.ctc_decode(predictions,
sequence_lengths=input_len)[0][0][:, :max_len]
prediction_model =
keras.models.Model(model.get_layer(name="image").output,
model.get_layer(name="dense2").output)
results = keras.ops.nn.ctc_decode(pred,
sequence_lengths=input_len)[0][0][:, :max_len] >

Here is the gist.
And in case the gist gets nuked:
class CTCLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, name=None):
    super().__init__(name=name)
    self.loss_fn = tf.keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost         #change to tf.keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost because keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost not in keras 3

def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
    batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
    input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
    label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

    input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
    label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
    loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
    self.add_loss(loss)

    # At test time, just return the computed predictions.
    return y_pred

def calculate_edit_distance(labels, predictions):
# Get a single batch and convert its labels to sparse tensors.
saprse_labels = tf.cast(tf.sparse.from_dense(labels), dtype=tf.int64)

# Make predictions and convert them to sparse tensors.
input_len = np.ones(predictions.shape[0]) * predictions.shape[1]
predictions_decoded = keras.ops.nn.ctc_decode(predictions, sequence_lengths=input_len)[0][0][:, :max_len]  #changes to keras.backend.ctc_decode to keras.ops.nn.ctc_decode
# predictions_decoded = keras.backend.ctc_decode(
#     predictions, input_length=input_len, greedy=True
# )[0][0][:, :max_len]
sparse_predictions = tf.cast(
    tf.sparse.from_dense(predictions_decoded), dtype=tf.int64
)

# Compute individual edit distances and average them out.
edit_distances = tf.edit_distance(
    sparse_predictions, saprse_labels, normalize=False
)
return tf.reduce_mean(edit_distances)

